# Load data dynamically in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8. I am new to it. My concern is i want to load data in a list from database.(for example contacts). But i want to dynamically load data when users tap up the screen as for performance. First i need to display of 10 contacts(for example) and when user taps down i need to load it dynamically.. can we do this in windows phone 8.. can we fire an event in windows or do we have any thing in the telerik controls...Or there was any other method to improve the performance.

Can any one please help me to find the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look of this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e) and [this is](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx) the description of how to create infinite LongListSelector in windows phone 8